# Qt QPixmap size

Tags: qt, qpixmap

I would to have a `QPixmap` with the size 50 x 50.
I tried :

```
QPixmap watermark(QSize(50,50)); 
watermark.load(":/icoMenu/preparation");
```

but the QPixmap take the image size.

I tried also :

```
QPixmap watermark(":/icoMenu/preparation");
watermark.scaled(QSize(50,50),  Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
```

but same result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You almost made it

```
QPixmap watermark(":/icoMenu/preparation");

QPixmap newPixmap = watermark.scaled(QSize(50,50),  Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
```